# Find $x,y,z\in\mathbb N$ where $x,y,z$ are lengths of a triangle and $x\le y\le z$, $x^2+y^2+z^2+126\le13(x+y+z)$, and $x^3+y^2+z=272$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, triangles

> Question:
>   Find $x,y,z\in\mathbb N$ where $x,y,z$ are lengths of a triangle and $x\le y\le z$, $x^2+y^2+z^2+126\le13(x+y+z)$, and $x^3+y^2+z=272$.

What I tried so far without any luck:
\begin{align}
&272=x^3+y^2+z> x+y+z>2z\rightarrow z<141\\
&272=x^3+y^2+z> x+y+z\ge3x\rightarrow x\le90\\
&x+y+z<x^2+y^2+z^2\le13(x+y+z)-126\rightarrow x+y+z>\frac{126}{12}\\
&x^2+y^2+z^2+126\le13(x+y+z)<13(x^2+y^2+z^2)\rightarrow x^2+y^2+z^2>\frac{126}{12}\\
&272=x^3+y^2+z>x^3\rightarrow x\le6\\
&272=x^3+y^2+z>y^2+y\rightarrow y\le15\\
&z<x+y\le21\\
&\cdots\\
\end{align}

Comment: $x=6, \ y=z=7$ seems to be the only solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first condition gives
$$(2x-13)^2+(2y-13)^2+(2z-13)^2\leq3,$$
which gives $$\{2x-13,2y-13,2z-13\}\subset\{1,-1\}$$
and the rest is smooth.